# Property of the Hamiltonian's discrete spectrum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, mathematics, eigenvalue

I have found a statement online saying that there must be an eigenvalue of the Hamiltonian inside the range $(E-\Delta H,E+\Delta H)$. Where the mean value and variance are defined for a random (normalized) wave function $| \psi \rangle $, so $E \equiv \langle \psi |H|\psi \rangle$ and $\Delta H \equiv \sqrt{\langle \psi |H^2|\psi \rangle-E^2}$.

Although this seems intuitively correct, I wanted to prove it. My limited experience in such cases is that firstly we expand $|\psi \rangle$ in the base defined by the eigenkets of $H$ meaning
$$|\psi \rangle =\sum\limits_n c_n \;|\psi_n \rangle \text{ where } c_n=\langle \psi_n|\psi\rangle\text{ complex numbers.} $$
We then have the expressions for $E,\;\Delta H$:
\begin{align}
E &=\sum\limits_n |c_n|^2 E_n\\
(\Delta H)^2&=\sum\limits_n |c_n|^2 E^2_n-\left(\sum\limits_n |c_n|^2 E_n \right)^2.
\end{align}
To be honest, I have no clue as to how to proceed, probably I need to take a random $E_m$ outside the sums and use an inequality to bound it above and below. If someone can give me a hint it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please give a detailed reference...

Comment: The notation is a bit vague, I think. If $\psi$ is an eigenstate of $H$, then the variance vanishes, and the expectation value is just the eigenvalue. But then $E\in (E,E)$ seems a bit...weird.

Comment: @TobiasFünke $\psi$ is a random normalized state not an eigenstate. I will try to find the and add it to the question. It was a problem I happened to come across while preparing for my QM exams, but couldn't solve at the time so I wanted to prove it now. The statement is that there is at least one eigenvalue inside that range, for a hermitian Hamiltonian.

Comment: I suppose the statement should hold for all $\psi$?! Then you can of course choose $\psi$ as an eigenstate, i.e. the statement in particular should hold for eigenstates, which leads to this weird notation, as I pointed out.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I see then the range should be a closed set, so in that case we would have $E_n \in [E_n,E_n]$, which of course is true. What I tried is to bound some random $E_m$ form above and below by $E \pm \Delta H$, but I seem to miss some trick or inequality. In that case what you are saying would be the special case where the equality holds.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the so-called Weinstein criterion.$^1$ To prove it, we proceed as OP and expand the (normalized) vector $\psi$ into the (assumed to be) complete orthonormal eigenbasis of $H$ and denote by $E_c$ the eigenvalue of $H$ which is closest to $E_\psi$. Then

$$(\Delta_\psi H)^2= \sum\limits_n \left(E_n-E_\psi\right)^2 |c_n|^2 \geq \left(E_c-E_\psi\right)^2  \tag 1  $$

and thus

$$(\Delta_\psi H)\geq |E_c-E_\psi| \tag 2\quad .$$

From the definition of the absolute value, this is equivalent with the fact that

$$-(\Delta_\psi H)\leq E_c-E_\psi \leq (\Delta_\psi H) \tag 3$$

or

$$ E_\psi-(\Delta_\psi H) \leq E_c \leq (\Delta_\psi H) +E_\psi\tag 4\quad ,$$

concluding the proof.

---

$^1$ *Weinstein, D. H. "Modified ritz method." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 20.9 (1934): 529-532.*

Comment: Thank you very much, yeah basically I was stuck by the form I chose for the variance. Also thanks for finding the name of the criterion.

Comment: @user20046481 Yes, with this form is much easier to do! Interesting problem, glad I could help.

Comment: It's indeed quite interesting and I suppose this result can be used for something like a variational method for higher energy states. For example if you manage to get a small variation for H through a test function you can say for sure you pinpointed an eigenvalue inside this range.

Answer (score 10):

Let us assume (for simplicity) that your Hamilton operator $H$ has a pure point spectrum with  spectral representation
$$ H= \sum\limits_n E_n |\phi_n \rangle \langle \phi_n |, \quad E_n \in \mathbb{R}, \; \langle \phi_m |\phi_n \rangle = \delta_{mn}, \; \sum\limits_n |\phi_n \rangle \langle \phi_n|= \mathbf{1}. $$ Assuming further that you have found some unit vector $|\psi\rangle$ with $$\langle \psi |H |\psi \rangle=E  \quad \text{and} \quad \langle \psi |(H-E)^2|\psi\rangle= (\Delta H)^2$$ with certain (fixed) values $E \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(\Delta H)^2 \ge 0$. You can expand the vector $|\psi\rangle$ with respect to the orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $H$, $$|\psi \rangle= \sum\limits_n c_n |\phi_n \rangle, \quad c_n=\langle \phi_n | \psi\rangle,$$ leading to $$(\Delta H)^2= \sum\limits |c_n|^2 (E_n-E)^2.$$  It is now the goal to show that at least one of the eigenvalues $E_n$ of $H$ must be in the interval $I= [E-\Delta H, E+\Delta H]$.

Proof by contradiction: Assume *all* $E_n$ are outside the interval $I$. In this case you have $|E_n-E|\gt \Delta H$ for all $n$, leading to the contradiction to the assumption: $$(\Delta H)^2= \sum\limits_n |c_n|^2 (E_n-E)^2 \gt (\Delta H)^2 \underbrace{\sum\limits_n |c_n|^2}_{=1} = (\Delta H)^2.$$

Comment: Nice alternative proof through contradiction. I liked the approach, although I marked Tobias one because it's more elegant and was first. Thanks for taking the time to write an answer.

Comment: @user20046481 Actually, this answer is more elegant in my opinion. In my answer, I assumed (just as the author of the original paper) that there exists a closest $E_c$. This is totally fine in finite-dimensions; however, in the infinite-dimensional case, I have the feeling that this doesn't always hold without further specifications. Hyperon's answer circumvents this issue (if it is true what I am thinking) completely.

Answer (score 5):

This is much simpler than it seems. Because only one observable ($H$) is involved, this property is not specific to quantum mechanics -- it is just a property of classical probability distributions.

Any probability distribution function (pdf) on the real numbers with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ must be nonzero *somewhere* in the interval $[\mu - \sigma, \mu + \sigma]$. Otherwise (if the support of the pdf were *entirely* outside this interval), there would be a contradiction, since the squared deviation of every observation from the mean, and hence its average (the variance), would be greater than $\sigma^2$.

The stated property is just the application of this result to the Born-rule probability distribution for outcomes of measuring $H$: There must be an outcome with nonzero probability (an eigenvalue) in the interval $[\mu - \sigma, \mu + \sigma]$.

Comment: The reason I said it seems intuitively correct was basically the interpretation I have for what variance and mean means. But I could have never phrased it the way you did, so as to be a complete argument. So thank you for providing this approach.